# Creating a DynamicMethod to set a readonly field on any type

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

My aim is to create a delegate at runtime which can set any field (including `readonly`) in any reference type to a user-specified value. Unfortunately, my current implementation throws a `VerificationException` at runtime when the assemblies containing the types specify the `[AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` attribute.

`AssemblyOne`:

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
public class TypeOne
{
    public TypeOne(TypeTwo typeTwoField)
    {
        this.TypeTwoField = typeTwoField;
    }

    public TypeTwo TypeTwoField { get; }
}
```

`AssemblyTwo`:

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
public class TypeTwo
{
    public TypeTwo(int i)
    {
        this.Int = i;
    }

    public int Int { get; }
}
```

`Main`:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using AssemblyOne;
using AssemblyTwo;

namespace Main
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyType
        {
            public MyType(TypeOne typeOneField)
            {
                this.TypeOneField = typeOneField;
            }

            public TypeOne TypeOneField { get; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fieldInfo = typeof(TypeOne)
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .GetField(
                    "<TypeTwoField>k__BackingField",
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Public);
            var setter = (Action<TypeOne, TypeTwo>) GetReferenceSetter(fieldInfo);
            var myType = new MyType(new TypeOne(new TypeTwo(1)));

            // Throws VerificationException
            setter(myType.TypeOneField, new TypeTwo(2));
        }

        public static Delegate GetReferenceSetter(FieldInfo field)
        {
            var delegateType = typeof(Action<,>)
                .MakeGenericType(field.DeclaringType, field.FieldType);

            var method = new DynamicMethod(
                field.Name + "Set",
                null,
                new[] {field.DeclaringType, field.FieldType},
                field.DeclaringType,
                skipVisibility: true);

            var emitter = method.GetILGenerator();
            emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
            emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            return method.CreateDelegate(delegateType);
        }
    }
}
```

So `MyType` has a `TypeOne` which has a readonly `TypeTwo`. In this scenario, the `DynamicMethod` throws a `VerificationException` at runtime.

Is it possible to create such a delegate which works for any declaring type + field type which you throw at it? If so, how?

I realize that `readonly` fields ought never be set after construction, but the purpose of this is for deserialization & deep-copying.

Comment: Confirmed that neither `stfld` nor `ldflda` work in this case. Are you open to more "hackish" approaches? By the way, `readonly` fields may be cached in the application, which means that the value you set may not be immediately visible.

Comment: I'm open to any kind of approach. This is for deserialization & deep-copying, so the object has just been constructed and no external code will have a chance to cache the value.

Comment: Please send feedback if my solution works.

Comment: Will do, and thank you @IllidanS4 :) Is SharpUtils available as a NuGet package? I couldn't find it

Comment: Sadly, no, but you can copy the relevant methods to your code. *FromMethodInfo* is just a shorthand to obtain the return type and parameter types of the method, and *NewCustomDelegateType* is a call to internal .NET methods.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic methods are quite limited in modifying their security. I suspect using an *AssemblyBuilder* instead may bypass the security checks, but I haven't tried that.

Instead, what *may* be able to achieve this is using other methods that access fields, in the *TypedReference* type.

```
public static unsafe void SetValue<T>(object inst, FieldInfo fi, T val)
{
    var mi = typeof(TypedReference).GetMethod("InternalMakeTypedReference", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    var sig = MethodSignature.FromMethodInfo(mi);
    var del = ReflectionTools.NewCustomDelegateType(sig.ReturnType, sig.ParameterTypes);
    var inv = mi.CreateDelegate(del);
    TypedReference tr;
    var ptr = Pointer.Box(&tr, typeof(void*));
    inv.DynamicInvoke(ptr, inst, new[]{fi.FieldHandle.Value}, fi.FieldType);
    __refvalue(tr, T) = val;
}
```

*FromMethodInfo* and *NewCustomDelegateType* are from *[SharpUtils](https://github.com/IllidanS4/SharpUtils)* and are required to invoke *InternalMakeTypedReference*, which is able to obtain a reference to any field. Its signature looks like this:

```
private unsafe static extern void InternalMakeTypedReference(void* result, object target, IntPtr[] flds, RuntimeType lastFieldType);
```

You can replace the library methods with your own, they are needed just to build the appropriate delegate type (*Action* cannot be used due to the pointer). You cannot create the delegate type directly because of the internal *RuntimeType*. Surprisingly, *DynamicInvoke* works on the delegate, and the type reference is created.

However, to use this voodoo, I had to lower the security checks in the assembly a bit, so I am not sure if it also works in your assembly system:

```
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1, SkipVerificationInFullTrust=true)]
```

Also please note that this code uses quite a number of undocumented features, and may stop working at any time. Use only at your own risk.

Comment: There is easier way how to create TypedReference: undocumented keyword __makeref: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38695/UnCommon-C-keywords-A-Look#makref

Comment: @frakon I know very well of `__makeref`, but it is not applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have some exits code may be help you.

```
/// <summary>
    /// create a getter delegate for a static field.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TField"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="staticType">the type that contains the field. </param>
    /// <param name="fieldName">the field that you want to get the value.</param>
    /// <returns>the getter delegate.</returns>
    public static Func<TField> CreateStaticFieldGetter<TField>(Type staticType, string fieldName)
    {
        var fieldInfo = staticType.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        var body = Expression.Field(null, fieldInfo);
        Expression<Func<TField>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TField>>(body);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }


    public static Action<TField> CreateStaticFieldSetter<TField>(Type staticType, string fieldName)
    {
        ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TField), "p1");
        var fieldInfo = staticType.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        var leftExpr = Expression.Field(null, fieldInfo);
        var body = Expression.Assign(leftExpr, p1);
        Expression<Action<TField>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<TField>>(body, p1);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }



    public static Func<TTarget, TField> CreateInstanceFieldGetter<TTarget, TField>(string fieldName)
    {
        ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), "p1");
        var fieldInfo = typeof(TTarget).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var body = Expression.Field(Expression.Convert(p1, typeof(TTarget)), fieldInfo);
        Expression<Func<TTarget, TField>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TTarget, TField>>(body, p1);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }



    public static Action<TTarget, TProperty> CreateInstanceFieldSetter<TTarget, TProperty>(string filedName)
    {
        ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), "p1");
        ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty), "p2");

        var member = typeof(TTarget).GetField(filedName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var m1 = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Convert(p1, typeof(TTarget)), member);
        BinaryExpression body = Expression.Assign(m1, p2);

        Expression<Action<TTarget, TProperty>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<TTarget, TProperty>>(body, p1, p2);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
```

Comment: I'd also suggest removing non-English documentation, and empty doc comments.

Comment: @Aimee Borada,  sorry, the code can not work while the field is readonly.